# How to count the length of JSON response in React Native/JS?

Tags: javascript

I would like to count the length of my response JSON. Here's my code:

```
getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
return fetch('http://sampleurl.com/' + CommonDataManager.getInstance().getUserID())
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, listMessages: responseJson});    
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You are welcome. The community also prefers titles written in natural English. Grammatically, "React How to count the length of a JSON response" doesn't make a lot of sense (though I understand the purpose of using "ReactJS" as a home-made tag). However, since we have a tagging system, it is better to merge the "tag" into the question, or get rid of it completely, since it is already in the tag list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Count the keys

```
  var myObject = {'key':'something', 'other-key':'something else','another-key': 'another thing'}
  var count = Object.keys(myObject).length;
```

Where `myObject` is your json response and `count` is the length of your object

This is the best way to count the json objects correctly

In your code you should add this in your second `.then`

```
var count = Object.keys(responseJson).length;
```

Comment: which part in my code should I replace myObject variable?.

Comment: Hi sir Joe can I call the count variable outside my function? or maybe to another file?.

Comment: thats an issue. you can declare it outside, but this is asynchronous and might not always be the expected value. 
I would suggest that if you need to use the value count for something you call that in the `.then` statement to ensure it exists. This is the entire point of a promise