# get amount of properties defined in state object react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

I have an `data` object in a state, like so:

```
this.state = {
        data: {
            newsData: [],
            eventData: [],
        },
    }
```

How can I get the number of properties defined in the state `data`? data.length doesn't work since it's not an array.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021238/how-to-count-the-length-of-json-response-in-react-native-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021238/how-to-count-the-length-of-json-response-in-react-native-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.values(data).length